# How to confirm coaxial wall plate is connected correctly?

Tags: coaxial-cable, tv-antenna

I connected coaxial cable to a wall plate plug that connects a [wire directly (does not use a terminator)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwBVv27QInQ).

[image]

After doing that, I did some connectivity testing from the back to the front, and I found that there is no connectivity between the outside middle pin connection and the internal pin.  The braided sheath has conductivity to the ring on the wall plate connector

I figured there is some type of signal processing involved so it may not be conductive... there are also capacitors on the wall plate plug so it's probably taking all the power.

How do I test to make sure that I installed this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your tester probably uses direct current (DC) which will be blocked by the capacitor.

The capacitor should pass the high frequency AC signal from the aerial.

Mind you, those are horrible cheap unscreened sockets. You'd be much better using the screened type with the metal cage which were shown in the rest of the video.